# Tab strip disappears on setting background color

Tags: android, android-tabs

i have made a tab view, i want to change the background color of the tabs, but when i set the color on the tab textview background, the strip disappears.

SlidingTabLayout.java

```
    package com.towntrot.checkin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;          
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

public interface TabColorizer {

    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    int getDividerColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
    }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

SlidingTabStrip.java

```
    package com.towntrot.checkin;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 2;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 4;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xffee7600;

private static final int DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 1;
private static final byte DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x20;
private static final float DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT = 0.5f;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

private final Paint mDividerPaint;
private final float mDividerHeight;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
    final int themeForegroundColor =  getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);

    mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setDividerColors(setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA));

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();

    mDividerHeight = DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT;
    mDividerPaint = new Paint();
    mDividerPaint.setStrokeWidth((int) (DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density));
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final int dividerHeightPx =0;
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);

    // Vertical separators between the titles
    int separatorTop = (height - dividerHeightPx) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        mDividerPaint.setColor(tabColorizer.getDividerColor(i));
        canvas.drawLine(child.getRight(), separatorTop, child.getRight(),
                separatorTop + dividerHeightPx, mDividerPaint);
    }
}

private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}

private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;
    private int[] mDividerColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }
        @Override
    public final int getDividerColor(int position) {
        return mDividerColors[position % mDividerColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }

    void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
        mDividerColors = colors;
    }
}
```

}

In createDefaultTabView i have added:

textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

I am new to android, any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you set background of textview, it covers yours SlidingTabStrip layout (container of tabs), which is below in your view hierarchy, so bottom strips are covered by TextView background.

To change background color of all of tabs, you should add drawing of background to `SlidingTabStrip.onDraw` method. To change background of all of the tabs, you can e.g. fill whole tabs container using `canvas.drawColor(int color)` method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final int dividerHeightPx =0;
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

   canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);

    // Vertical separators between the titles
    int separatorTop = (height - dividerHeightPx) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        mDividerPaint.setColor(tabColorizer.getDividerColor(i));
        canvas.drawLine(child.getRight(), separatorTop, child.getRight(),
                separatorTop + dividerHeightPx, mDividerPaint);
    }
}
```